# How to implement background local notification in PWA?

Tags: reactjs, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I'm making an expense tracker progressive web app. We need a feature where the user is notified/reminded every night to input their expense on the app.

Here is the pseudocode that I came up with, but have no idea how to implement it with JavaScript/React PWA.

```js
if (time == 07.00PM) {
  sendNotification();
}
```

Any idea how to get the time while the app is in background and send the notification?

Thank you very much

---

I've tried some attempt with:

1. [react-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-push-notification)
2. Manually adding the notification

```js
// notification.js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Notification.requestPermission().then(perm => {
    if (perm === 'granted') {
      const notification = new Notification('Contoh', {
        body: "Cek 123",
        icon: "logo.png"
      });
      notification.addEventListener("error", e => {
        alert("error");
      })
    }
  })
});
```

[Full GitHub repository](https://github.com/faizbyp/pwafromscratch)